# jquery define custom event

Tags: jquery, events

I'm an intermediate JS programmer and it's a world of difference from PHP (esp. when I'm not an OOP programmer even in PHP).

I am interested in defining my own events in jQuery as a possible simplification of my programming, and I'll use a simple example:

often you have rows of records in a table.  user wants to make a row inactive.  System is set so that when this happens the row fades out and disappears.  Let's suppose there could be 3 ways to do this:

1. hit an inactive icon
2. with the row highlighted hit <kbd>i</kbd> or
3. right click and select inactive from a context menu.

what I'd like to do is something like:

```
$('.datarow').on('rowinactive',function(){ /* etc */ });
```

any of the three actions above would set `$('#row12345')` as `.inactive`, and the event handler would take it from there.  I see it as you have somewhat of a separation between the state and the action(s) related to the state.

I hope this is a simple example to start.  Can anyone offer some example code for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can define pretty much any event you'd like, but such events would have to be triggered somewhow.

```
$('.datarow').on('rowinactive',function(e, elem){
    alert(elem.id + ' is inactive');
});

$('table tr').on('click', function() {
    $(this).highlight();
    $('.datarow').trigger('rowinactive', this); // passes the element
});
```

you can also pass any parameter to the triggered function.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jBPyj/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("input").on('customEvent',function(){ //define a custom event listener
        $("p").text("hello");
    });
    $("input").trigger('customEvent'); //call the event listener attached to obj. with name 'customEvent'
});
```

I've made an example which you can play with [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/buHTm/). You could exapnd this idea to apply a a custom event to multiple objects collected by a specifict `$(...)`. Then as each object may have a different interaction with the user, you can invoke the action appropriatley, i.e for an input you might trigger `customEvent` on `click`, while another when it's `inactive` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Without the markup is a bit difficult to help, so i'll make an example using only the hypothetical "inactivate" icon.

```
$('.inactive-icon').on('click',function(){
    var $row = $(this).closest('.datarow');
    $row.fadeOut(500,function(){
        $row.trigger('inactive'); // ---> it's that simple!
    });
});

$('.datarow').on('inactive',function(){ /* etc */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jloureiro09/T22as/).

```
$("tr").bind("fadeOut", function(){ /* code */ });
$("tr").trigger("fadeOut");
```